# where to save custom autoloaders in zend?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, zend-framework

I am trying to use [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/) in my application by making a custom autoloader.

```
class My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface {

   static protected $php_thumb_classes = array(
      'PhpThumb'        => 'PhpThumb.inc.php',
      'ThumbBase'       => 'ThumbBase.inc.php',
      'PhpThumbFactory' => 'ThumbLib.inc.php',
      'GdThumb'         => 'GdThumb.inc.php',
      'GdReflectionLib' => 'thumb_plugins/gd_reflection.inc.php',
   );

  /**
   * Autoload a class
   *
   * @param   string $class
   * @return  mixed
   *          False [if unable to load $class]
   *          get_class($class) [if $class is successfully loaded]
   */
   public function autoload($class) {
      $file = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/PhpThumb/' . self::$php_thumb_classes[$class];
      if (is_file($file)) {
         require_once($file);
         return $class;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

i saved this file as `PhpThumb.php` in the `loaders/Autoloader` folder. Then added this line to the bootstrap file:

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->pushAutoloader(new My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb());
```

But it produces an error saying the class was not found. I am guessing that the 'CustomLoader_PhpThumb.php' needs to be saved somewhere else. Any idea guys ?

---

Update1:

Bootstrap.php file contents

```
   <?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoLoader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $resourceLoader=new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace'=>'',
            'resourceTypes'=>array(
                'form'=>array(
                    'path'=>'forms/',
                    'namespace'=>'Form_'
                ),
                'models'=>array(
                    'path'=>'models/',
                    'namespace'=>'Model_'
                ),                
            )

            ));

        //return $autoLoader;

        $resourceLoader->addResourceType('loader', 'loaders/', 'My_Loader_');

        $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);
        $autoLoader->pushAutoloader(new My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb());
    }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm also using PhpThumb and the same autoloader. In my case however it is called `My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb` and is located in `APPLICATION_PATH . '/loaders/Autoloader/PhpThumb.php`.

In my Bootstrap.php, first I load the loaders path to the Zend_Loader_Autoloader and then I push the `My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb` autoloader as follows:

```
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
                'namespace' => '',
            ));


    $resourceLoader->addResourceType('loader', 'loaders/', 'My_Loader_');

    $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);
    $autoLoader->pushAutoloader(new My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb());
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: the loader is working great but my controllers cant find the PhpThumb class. using $thumb = My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumbFactory::create($imagePath) doesnt work

Comment: @anp. It does not work because class My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumbFactor does not exists. If you want to use PhpThumbFactory, just use PhpThumbFactory::create($imagePath) in your controllers. ZF autoloader, through the new autoloader will worry how to load PhpThumbFactory.

Comment: using `PhpThumbFactory::create($imagePath)` also says `Class 'PhpThumbFactory' not found`. i have added contents of bootstrap in above post for you to see.

Comment: @anp. I think you should pushAutoloader your $resourceLoader as well as the My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb(), as in my anwser. Also you don't need to  return $autoLoader as this is singleton, and always one instance exists and no need to worry you will have two different autoloaders.

Comment: @Marcin if i use `pushAutoloader`, bootstrap gives an error saying `Class 'My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb' not found`

Comment: @anp. What is confusing for me is that you do not push $resourceLoader. In your _initAutoload(), $resourceLoader is defined but you seem not to do anything with it. I think you should push it to $autoLoader.

Comment: well i just did that but still no progress (see above). am i still doing something wrong ?

Comment: @anp. To my knowledge it should be ok now. So the problem now must be somewhere else. The only thing that comes to my mind right now is to check paths if they are correct.

Comment: @anp. Good it works finally:-) I also was about to post, that as a quick solution you could load My_Loader_Autoloader_PhpThumb manually:  require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/loaders/Autoloader/PhpThumb.php';

Comment: Where abouts in the Bootstrap.php does the code go? I just put it at the top and it works, but is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

`PhpThumb.php` should be saved to `library/CustomLoader` folder, and you should setup autoloader for this class also, for example in `application.ini`:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "CustomLoader_"
```

or in `Bootstrap.php`:

```
$autoloader->registerNamespace('CustomLoader_');
```

I couldn't try, I hope it works!

Comment: but for this to work, i think phpThumb's class names should start with 'CustomLoader_' prefix and it doesn't. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Oh, I made mistake! Class name should be `CustomLoader_PhpThumb` and file name should be `PhpThumb.php`

Answer (score 0):

I did it in another way, long more easy, without any autoloader, just using "My".

1.- Create a phpThumbFolder with all the files of the library into project/library/My/PhpThumb

2.- Create a file named PhpThumbFactory.php into that folder with the following content:

```
require_once('ThumbLib.inc.php');

class My_PhpThumb_PhpThumbFactory
{
   public static function create ($filename = null, $options = array(), $isDataStream = false)
   {
       return PhpThumbFactory::create($filename, $options, $isDataStream);
   }
}
```

3.- Enjoy:

```
public function editimageAction()
{
    //rutaImg is the physical path to my images defined in application.ini
    $rutaImg = Zend_Registry::get('config')->rutaImg. "test.jpg";

    //Call to our "gateway" class
    $thumb = My_PhpThumb_PhpThumbFactory::create($rutaImg);
    //Resize
    $thumb->adaptiveResize(20, 20);
    //Show
    $thumb->show();

    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
}
```

I hope it can help anyone ;)

P.D. The "gateway" class is to avoid modifying any code of the library, so any possible update is easy.